# How to remove name from ir.actions.act_window (Odoo)

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb

I want to remove the name 'Point of Sale', then I did this in a custom module:

```
<record id="point_of_sale.action_pos_config_kanban" model="ir.actions.act_window">        
    <field name="name"> </field>
</record>
```

This is the result:

[image]

How to remove the 'Unnamed' using custom module? I am using odoo 13

Update: more specifically. how do I remove `<em class="text-warning">Unnamed</em>`
I don't need this warning -_-

I tried: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_cyPsVc7vg to set `_rec_name`, but no luck

Sample:

```
class PosCustomConfig(models.Model):

    _inherit = ['pos.config']

    _rec_name =  fields.Char(' ', size=64)
```

Comment: You should add name field in your model and add related in this name field

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did this to replace the entire `breadcrumb`

```
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ControlPanel">
        <t t-jquery="ol.breadcrumb" t-operation="replace">
            <div></div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

add the `custom.xml` in  `__manifest__.py` under `'qweb'`